# Making your website appear using a jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to know how to make my website appear with jquery animations for example if

```
body {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

how could I use jquery to make it

```
body {
visibility: visible;
}
```

but have it animate like you can animate a dialog box with

```
show:"fold"
```

make sense?

Comment: In future please just edit your original post if it didn't have any answers. Thanks.

Comment: is it ok if I just delete it and start a new one?

Comment: Well as long as you delete it right away. But having two questions with the exact same title is just going to cause you grief due to flagging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/esqew/aBzXs/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle is set to MooTools, but otherwise, looking nice.

Comment: @esqew, place a delay to make it more perceptible! (just a suggestion)

Comment: @recursive I could have sworn I had changed it, because it had worked for me! Oh well, thanks for the catch. Updated.

Comment: @Zuul Personally, I'd add a small delay as well but the OP never mentioned anything about it. If he wants a delay, he can most certainly ask me to add it in.

Comment: @esqew is it possible to write the code so that i could choose an animation for it to make the element appear with? because i have code to make it fade in like you just did alrdy...

Comment: @TechbyTbone What? Just choose which CSS properties to animate and change the code in the applicable locations and you're done.

Comment: @esqew tis not working great sir, the first set of code not with adding a animation http://timothy.techbypaul.com/index.php

Comment: @TechbyTbone It's because you're not making your body's `visibility` visible anywhere in your code... also in good practice (although it should work) you should put your JS somewhere else besides your analytics js file.

Comment: sigh w/e I can't figure this out ive got an error that is probably causing the code to stop working and here is the code i copied from you $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css({
        opacity: 0.0,
        visibility: "visible"
    }).animate({
            opacity: 1.0
});

Comment: Do you not understand Javascript?

Comment: one more question if i wanted it to become visible not by fading in but by using an animation like fold or clip how would i do that?

Comment: If you're using jQueryUI (by the looks of the source of your page) you can use it's [more advanced show animations](http://jqueryui.com/docs/show/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

js:

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(document).ready(function () {$("body").show("slide");});
```

css:

```
body {
    display:none;
}
```

And with this solution you can change what animation you want change "slide" to any other jQuery UI effects http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/